# How to evaluate the following integral $\int \frac{\sin^2 x}{(x\cos x-\sin x)^2} dx$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

From the above I can only get:$$\int \frac{1}{(x\cot x-1)^2} dx$$
Then I have no ideas. Is there anyone helping me? Any tips are useful.

Comment: http://calculus-calculator.com/integral gives me $\dfrac{\sin(2x)-x\cos(2x)-x}{2x\sin(2x)-x^2\cos(2x)+\cos(2x)-x^2-1}+C$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int\frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{(x\cos(x)-\sin(x))^{2}}dx=\int\frac{\tan^{2}(x)}{(x-\tan(x))^{2}}dx$$
Now try the substitution $u=x-\tan(x)$

Comment: It should work, $1-\sec^2{x}=-\tan^2{x}$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
The integrand resembles the formula $\ds{\pars{\fermi \over {\rm g}}'
={\fermi'{\rm g} - {\rm g}'\fermi\over {\rm g}^{2}}}$. Then we 'rebuild' the formula to check if that sort is true:

> \begin{align}
> &\int{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over \bracks{x\cos\pars{x} - \sin\pars{x}}^{2}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\int{-\sin\pars{x}\bracks{x\cos\pars{x} - \sin\pars{x}}
>    -\bracks{\cos\pars{x} - x\sin\pars{x} - \cos\pars{x}}\cos\pars{x}
>    \over \bracks{x\cos\pars{x} - \sin\pars{x}}^{2}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\int\totald{}{x}\bracks{\cos\pars{x} \over x\cos\pars{x} - \sin\pars{x}}
> \,\dd x = {\cos\pars{x} \over x\cos\pars{x} - \sin\pars{x}} + \mbox{a constant}
> \end{align}

Comment: @Timothy In order to check if your suspiction is true you set $g(x)=x\cos(x) - \sin(x)$. With this you get ${f'[x\cos(x) - \sin(x)] -[-x\sin(x)]f\over g^{2}}$. Now, by trial and error you see that $f(x) = \cos(x)$ cancels the terms $\propto x$. Well, maybe it's a simple case but in general you can set a first order equation for $f(x)$: $f'g - g'f = \sin^{2}(x)$. 'Trial and error' whenever it's simple.

Comment: Thanks. It's the first that I have known the method. But in my textbook, $(fg)'=f'g-g'f$. But your formula is different. I'm confused.

Comment: @Timothy Sorry. That was a typo. I already fixed.

Comment: Thanks. But I prefer Daniel's answer, because his answer is simpler.

Comment: @Timothy Fine. No problem. Thanks.